# How do I delete mysql data based on timestamp?

Tags: mysql

I am using System.Data.SqlLite.dll lite version 1.0.105.0

I have a very simple MySQL database.

I create a single table in the Database using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE SessionInfo (session nvarchar(100), state nvarchar(25), ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I (successfully) add data to the table:

```
INSERT INTO SessionInfo (session, state) VALUES ('test', '1')
```

When I try to purge data from the table using this statement:

```
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts < ADDDATE( NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MINUTE )
```

(I have also tried the following)

```
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1' minute
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

In all cases, I get this error:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled
ErrorCode=1
HResult=-2147467259
Message=SQL logic error or missing database
near "MINUTE": syntax error
Source=System.Data.SQLite
```

When I try either of these:

```
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts < NOW() - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
```

I get this error:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled
ErrorCode=1
HResult=-2147467259
Message=SQL logic error or missing database
near "'1'": syntax error
Source=System.Data.SQLite
```

I tried wrapping timestamp in UNIX_TIMESTAMP macro...

```
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) < 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE))
```

Still same error:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled
ErrorCode=1
HResult=-2147467259
Message=SQL logic error or missing database
near "1": syntax error
Source=System.Data.SQLite
```

I tried deleting records in between timestamps:

```
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts between now() - interval 1 hour and now()
```

I still get the same result:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled
ErrorCode=1
HResult=-2147467259
Message=SQL logic error or missing database
near "1": syntax error
```

So, I just tried this:

```
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and ALL of my records are deleted... so I know I can delete... just not the stuff I want to delete

Thanks to LSerni, here is my working code:
( note: I was using minutes for testing... but real code will be in days )

```
DELETE FROM SessionInfo WHERE ts < DATETIME('NOW', '-7 DAY')
```

Comment: Have you tried using between? WHERE ts between now() - interval 1 hour and now()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MySQL syntax, but SQLite does not support it. There is no `NOW()` function, nor there is a date adding function. You must use [date modifiers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Try:

```
 SELECT DATETIME('NOW', '-1 MINUTE');
```

or

```
 DELETE ... WHERE ts < DATETIME('NOW', '-1 MINUTE');
```

Comment: OMG... THANK YOU... this is so exasperating... I guess that's why it's SQL 'LITE'  ...